# Using ui-router - is there a way to provide a path to controller file ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a very basic angular app using ui-router, and I have 3 "modules" right now, which are `home`, `login`, and `register`.  Here is how I have defined them:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('exampleApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: './main/home/home.html',
      controller: './main/home/home-controller.js'
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: './main/login/login.html',
      controller: './main/login/login-controller.js'
    })
    .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: './main/register/register.html',
      controller: './main/register/register-controller.js'
    })
})
```

However, I think I am doing the `controller:` portion wrong.  I want to define each controller for each "module", and I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Here's my file structure -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First define your controller.**

```
angular.module('exampleApp').controller('loginCtrl', function () { 
 // ctrl task goes here.
});
```

**Mapping controller to a route.**

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
              url: '/login',
              templateUrl: 'path/to/login.html',
              controller: 'loginCtrl'
            })
```

Comment: will this controller go inside the app.module.js file then?  that is the file in which i am defining the states.  if so, i am wondering how can i put the controller in the login folder. thanks

Comment: You can do something like `app.controller` in the file where you have defined the `app` and the `states`, that will be if you are trying to learn the concept, but in practice, controllers are kept in separate js file.